# Is it possible to use links file java class files instead of copying them into project in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-library

I have many java class files written by me for common purposes which I need to use very often in my Android projects. These classes (let's call them 'library') has many static methods in them and I call these methods when I need them in my Android Studio projects without any problem

When I create a new Android Studio project I copy all those library files into the Java folder of my new project. So, I can call them with the syntax like classname.methodname() at any time in my projects (in activities, in other java classes, etc)

The question is that this technic causes many independent library files in each project. This means that, when I have added a new method or changed a method, I need to do the same thing at each library files in each project.

As I am new at Android Studio and I am playing with that at the moment, this might be ok. But in real life, this will be impossible in the near future while I was struggling with many projects.

I am sure that, there should be a way to use file links instead of inserting these library files by copying them into the Android projects. So, making changes in a source library file will affect all projects at once. Something like $I directive in the C type languages...

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Thank you...

Comment: One option: Create a separate project for your library, publish releases of it to a repository (e.g. Maven Central, Maven Local (if you only need it on your computer), JCenter, your own personal repo, etc.), declare a dependency on your library in the Gradle build script, use your library like any other published library you might be using. Though note publishing your library to a public repository such as Maven Central will make it available to everyone (and I don't believe you can remove it).

Answer (score 0):

One good way would be to create your own library/module in android studio.

Here is a link for that : https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

And another way would be to create your own JAR file.